# What should I do if I want to add 100 to each number in Ubuntu vi Editor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vi

What should I do if I want to add 100 to each number in Ubuntu vi Editor?
The file I am trying to change contains numbers from 0 to 100 in ().
I want to add 100 to all the numbers in these brackets.

Examples

```
<Original File>
(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
```

```
<Changed File>
(101)
(102)
(103)
(104)
```

Please help me!

Comment: Write yourself a bash script which does exactly what you want.

Comment: The place to ask questions about using `vi` is [vi.se]

Comment: `1G!Gawk '{ ...`

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, I would pipe this to awk.  There's got to be a cleaner way to do this in vim, but the following (seems to) work:

```
:g/(\d*)/s/(\(\d*\))/\="(".(submatch(1)+100).")"/g
```